# How do I trigger a email in Magento when an order is made?

Tags: email, magento, triggers

I need solution for the following:
1) Customer places order
2) Store owner recieves email WITHOUT price info (e.g. packing list)

What files do I need to edit (I've read lots of posts and they don't seem to mention the file paths).

Thx

Comment: Check out app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html - I think you'll need custom logic for separate email for customer vs admin

Comment: @sparcksoft, that's exactly what I did. I'll find the code and post into an answer.

Comment: Hi everyone, I was able to find: http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/

This seems to work great, the only thing is when I follow the steps, it sends an email, but with all the variables as empty (despite the fact that I copied the email EXACTLY' from the new order template.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to achieve that:

1. You can create a model rewrite for the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and override the function `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` by sending an email to the shop owner using a different template
2. You can set the configuration entry "Sales Email/Order/Send Order Email Copy To" to nothing (so that the shop owner doesn't get the same email as the customer), and implement an observer catching the event `sales_order_place_after`. In the observer function you implement sending of an email to the shop owner using a template without the price info.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. In your experience which would be most advisable? Essentially all I need to do is send the same email twice, but just have one without prices.

Answer (score 1):

I know I had a hack for it ... and then I don't have it anymore. I went through everything I could and right now, we're CCing ourselves the customer notification email. As soon as we're done with our site upgrade, I'll have to readd my hack. I'm pretty sure it's in `app/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` possibly in `public function sendNewOrderEmail()`

See this pic:
[image: Magento Transaction Emails]

I remember hard coding in a file after the customer notification was sent, we sent another one to admin but hard coding the template ID for the transactional order notification email to 8. Now, somehow, I'm doing it the "right way" but have no idea how I'm triggering this transactional email to ALSO happen with the customer order notification.

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom module in that module just send a event after "sales_order_save_after".
Catch this event in observer file and put your custum coding on observer.
[Read this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)