# How to send two emails after checkout?

Tags: magento

everyone! Please help me. I'm using Magento to configure a virtual store and, apart from the default email that is sent when an order is placed, I need a second additional email to be sent to the same customer, with only instructions. I need both emails being sent at the same time. And more, I wanted this second email to be sent with an image. Is that possible? Thank you very much if anyone can help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in coding and if the two mails are not related then you can simply create a new Transactional Email(merging content from both emails) by navigating to `System -> Transactional Email` and then creating a new template from using load template for existing order template.

In the new template you are free to add image or text.

After saving this template you have to assign this template to Order Success Email in `System -> Configuration -> Sales Email` by choosing the correct template from drop down.

**But** if you really need two separate emails then you have to create a module for the second email by using Magento event `sales_order_place_after` and write the code to load any template and send mail. You will easily get information to do that in google or stack overflow ([How do I trigger a email in Magento when an order is made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712407/how-do-i-trigger-a-email-in-magento-when-an-order-is-made)).

You can try the way and get back here if you face any issue with the code.

Comment: Hi friend. Thank you so much. I will try to do that!!

Comment: Pls mark this answer useful if you think it was helpful to you.